# ClassNotFoundException issues using org.apache.commons.collections in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons, import-libraries

I'm very new to Eclipse (I used to use InteliJ) and I've got much of it sorted out but this is an issue that I just can't wrap my head arounds. I'm not sure if this has been asked already and I'm simply not asking the correct question so please be merciful. I need to emphasize that this code worked as intended when I was running it in InteliJ so it's not an issue with the code as far as I can see.

The program uses JavaFX and the bi-directional hashmap from the commons.collections and JavaFX does run properly.

The issue occurs when I attempt to use the commons.collections in the eclipse project. I added the library in the same way that I added the JavaFX files but when it runs, I get this error message.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.BidiMap

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and my google searches just keep turning me towards Maven but I don't want to use Maven if I can avoid it. [image: Picture of Eclipse]

I've included a picture of the library setup from InteliJ as well and from what I can tell, I need to include the Javadocs folder but I can't seem to find out how. Nothing I've done thus far has given much of a hint.

[image]

I really appreciate any help at all!

> UPDATE

I added the commons-collections4-4.4 to my class path and the same error is occurring.

Picture Included
[image]

Comment: Add the lib in your class path if eclipe org.apache.commons.collections

Comment: @Innovation I added the folder containing the collections library like you suggested and the error is persisting. I also set the Javadoc location value. I'm not sure if I missed something or if I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Innovation So I did in fact misunderstand. I added external class folder instead of adding external Jars. Once I did that, the issue went away. Thank you very much!

Comment: Even if someone wanted to flag a post as a duplicate the amount of ClassNotFoundException posts are too damn high.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix my issue, I needed to add the library to my class path. I had added it to my module path but that simply wasn't enough as it turns out.

This page can be accessed using

*properties -> Java Build Path -> libraries*.

One thing I learned is that it's best to click the "Add External JARS..." and not "Add External Class Folder".

Here's an example of my final configuration.

[image]